# Data access speed in LUKS encrypted partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, encryption, luks

In Linux (Fedora 28) I have my home directory LUKS encryped, when using Gnome Disk (screenshot), I can benchmark separately the underlying LUKS partition (upper blue rectangle) and the decrypted home partition (lower white rectanble).

The LUKS partition gives an access time of 500MB/s, but the decryped acces gives 350MB/s. To be clear this is the same partition a 500GB SSD.

**Is it fair to conclude that *encryption* is slowing down data access by 30% ( = 150/500)?**

Is this type of number documented or I am doing some thing wrong.
This is much more slowdown that I was expecting.

[image: screenshotdisks]

---

**EDIT:** This is my output for

```
$ cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1       384375 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256     494611 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512     323634 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  293225 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  185917 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       4 iterations, 748334 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      4 iterations, 745443 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b       195.0 MiB/s       664.0 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b        28.8 MiB/s        94.7 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        128b        58.8 MiB/s       111.6 MiB/s
        aes-cbc        256b       146.5 MiB/s       507.3 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b        33.3 MiB/s       110.2 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        256b        59.3 MiB/s       123.6 MiB/s
        aes-xts        256b       433.7 MiB/s       416.8 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b       101.0 MiB/s        94.7 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        256b       111.8 MiB/s       110.3 MiB/s
        aes-xts        512b       349.5 MiB/s       356.6 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b       101.6 MiB/s        96.0 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        512b       111.2 MiB/s       108.1 MiB/s
```

---

```
$ lscpu | grep aes
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge 
mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall
 nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology
 nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est 
tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer
 aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp
 tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm 
ida arat pln pts flush_l1d
```

---

**EDIT 2020:** I changed my computer and I get completely different results for the crypo benchmark, much beyond what can be explained by a faster processor.
So, I think my old hardware didn't have the dedicated encryption chip:

```
$ cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1      1756408 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256    2264742 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512    1653905 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  949797 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  711381 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       8 iterations, 1048576 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      8 iterations, 1048576 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b      1256.4 MiB/s      3669.2 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b       101.6 MiB/s       771.8 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        128b       230.0 MiB/s       418.4 MiB/s
        aes-cbc        256b       947.9 MiB/s      2961.6 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b       105.1 MiB/s       785.0 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        256b       235.7 MiB/s       424.5 MiB/s
        aes-xts        256b      2209.9 MiB/s      2218.9 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b       762.0 MiB/s       776.6 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        256b       415.7 MiB/s       384.0 MiB/s
        aes-xts        512b      1701.8 MiB/s      1677.2 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b       713.7 MiB/s       769.6 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        512b       407.9 MiB/s       414.2 MiB/s
```

Comment: Does your CPU support AES-NI or equivalent? Can you check `cryptsetup benchmark`?

Comment: Yes, it's a fair conclusion.

Comment: @grawity, I don't know, how can I find out? do you think there is a better way to tune the disk encryption for a given CPU (mine is Intel® Core™ i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz × 8  Intel® Ivybridge Mobile). I edited my question with the output of `cryptsetup benchmark`.

Comment: Run `lscpu | grep aes`, additionally `lsmod | grep aes` and just in case `modinfo aesni_intel`. According to [Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/products/67356/Intel-Core-i7-3612QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-10-GHz-rPGA) it should be supported, but on your benchmark it doesn't show.

Comment: `lscpu | grep aes` shows `aes` (see the edit in my question). `lsmod | grep aes` shows nothing. `modinfo easni_intel` gives `modinfo: ERROR: Module aesni_intel not found.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encryption adds extra CPU load, as each disk block needs to be decrypted by the OS on access. Your test results (~600 MB/s decryption) are fairly average for generic AES processing on an i7.

To avoid this issue, modern CPUs generally come with hardware-based AES support built in. Intel calls this feature "AES-NI" (shown in `lscpu` as "aes"), and it allows reaching 2–3 GB/s rates for the same AES decryption.

First run `lscpu` and check whether it mentions "aes" among feature flags. The [Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/products/67356/Intel-Core-i7-3612QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-10-GHz-rPGA) shows it as present in your CPU model, but it may be disabled by firmware (BIOS) settings. (The ARK has a footnote: *"Some products can support AES New Instructions with a Processor Configuration update … Please contact OEM for the BIOS that includes the latest Processor configuration update."*)

Linux uses the "aesni_intel" module to enable hardware acceleration. Check whether it's enabled in your kernel at all by running `zgrep AES_NI_INTEL /proc/config.gz`. If it shows "`=y`", it's part of the main kernel image and should be available.

If the output shows "`=m`", it's been compiled as a module – try to load the module manually by running `sudo modprobe -v aesni_intel`. If the command is unable to find the module, you probably have to reboot. (After reboot, make sure `uname -r` shows the same kernel version as in `ls /lib/modules`.)

Comment: `lscpu` shows a `aes` entry. `zgrep AES_NI_INTEL /proc/config.gz` gives
`gzip: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory`. `sudo modprobe -v aesni_intel` (after password) shows no output and the speed test still give the same results. `lsmod | grep aes` gives no output and  `modinfo aesni_intel` gives `modinfo: ERROR: Module aesni_intel not found`. Now I am curious why my Fedora doesn't seem to have this.